# Navbar element position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make a navbar (with bootstrap).
When the media's width is > 768px I want the navbar to be on the right (so I added float: right). But when the width is <768px I want the hamburger to be on the right (like it does right now), and the element to be centered.
This is how it looks right now.
[image: current situation]

Comment: post your code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad this to your responsive code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Here is a working [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegVEr)

Comment: @nadiaeagle lol I know.  Some people downvote without reading.  I don't know why.  It's cool.  Lol